# TypeError : undefined is not a function(near '...props.items.map...')

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, typeerror

Getting Error when I am trying to call values from my CartItem Object.
TypeError : undefined is not a function(near '...props.items.map...')
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
const OrderItem = (props) => {
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.orderItem}>
      <View style={styles.summary}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.detailsbtn}
          onPress={() => {
            setShowDetails((prevState) => !prevState);
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.id}>
            {showDetails ? 'Hide Details' : 'Details'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
      </View>

      {showDetails && (
        <View style={styles.detailItems}>
          {props.items.map((cartItem) => (
            <CartItem
              key={cartItem.productId}
              quantity={cartItem.quantity}
              amount={cartItem.sum}
              title={cartItem.productTitle}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Most likely `props.items` hasn't loaded yet or it is empty. Adding `{props.items && props.items.map...}` should prevent the error

Comment: I think ..props.items.map... will work on an array, here my items is an object. Any way I can convert the object to array?

Comment: Yes, `map` method works for arrays. [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) converts an object to an array if it would help you.

Comment: I tried using it but I am unable to do so, can you kindly show how to?

Comment: Let me know please, what is the value of props.items

Comment: In the Cartscreen:
-------------
const cartItems = useSelector((state) => {
    const transformedCartItems = [];
    for (const key in state.cart.items) {
      transformedCartItems.push({
        productId: key,
        productTitle: state.cart.items[key].productTitle,
        productPrice: state.cart.items[key].productPrice,
        quantity: state.cart.items[key].quantity,
        productimageUrl: state.cart.items[key].productimageUrl,
      });
------------
And in the paymentscreen :
--------------
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart.items);

Comment: It is difficult to me to figure out where is the issue exactly, because I cannot debug your code. You can log data which you are sending through Component to console, and make sure you are sending array of objects to the OrderItem component in proper structure(with all required keys)